# Setting the theorem environment manually

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I am writing up some problem solutions from a textbook.

For Chapter 1, I want to start off with Problem 1.36, rather than with 1.1

How do I accomplish this?

Below is my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,epsfig,epstopdf,titling,url,array}


\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem*{cor}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{prob}[thm]{Problem}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{conj}{Conjecture}[section]
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}[section]

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{rem}{Remark}
\newtheorem*{note}{Note}

\begin{document}

\section{Chapter 1}

\begin{prob}

This should Read Problem 1.36, rather than 1.1

\end{prob}



\end{document}
```

EDIT: I want to be able to continue on to 1.37 and 1.38 rather than 1.2 and 1.3. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `\setcounter{thm}{35}`? However, as you are using the same counter for many things this may result in unwanted effects...

Comment: Where does the number 36 come from? As it's written, your code makes problems share the numbering with theorems, lemmas and propositions. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

Set

> theoremstyle{Definition}

and add the

> \newtheorem*{prob*}

in the preamble. Hope this helps. I am attaching a screenshot of the same. Also, make sure you use the `{amsthm}` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,epsfig,epstopdf,titling,url,array,amsthm}
\theoremstyle{Definition}
\newtheorem*{prob*}{Problem 1.36}
\begin{document}

\section{Chapter 1}

\begin{prob*}

This should Read Problem 1.36, rather than 1.1

\end{prob*}



\end{document}
```

[image]